# Expressionengine 2 Login screen on Front Page

Tags: forms, authentication, expressionengine

I would like to create a login screen for registered members on front page of the site without using members module. As I can see I can create a member and assign login credentials at back-end ( I don't have member module). Basically the idea is:

visiting: www.domain.com will give you login screen. When logged in it will redirect you or open new page.

I'm not looking to buy a module or extension. If something already exist I will be happy to use it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You "don't have the members module"? How is that possible - it comes with the default install! So, something does already exist - it's called the [Login Form tag](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/member/index.html#id15).

Comment: if you have freelance license you will not get member module. And Login Form Tag will not work!

Comment: If you have a freelance license and you have members to manage then you bought the wrong license. :)

Comment: My client have non-commercial license and same thing there...Login Form tag generates error: No module exist and I dont see it in Modules. I have done more than 1 installations of EE2 on different platforms.

Comment: Non-commercial licenses *do* include the Member module, it may just be disabled. Visit Add-ons --> Modules to check. If it's not there, re-download a fresh install from their expressionengine.com account.

Comment: Ok in my commercial license I have it. Thank you but it is not a solution for someone to create login page. It shouldn't be UPGRADED version. Should be a simple solution for developers to lock page from viewing and grant access to members since member tab is available for member registration from admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

So is the question how to create a login form on the front end of the site, or how to keep non-logged in users from viewing a specific template?

If it's the latter you can set access privileges at the template level.  Look for the "Access" link by each template in the Template Manager, click that and you'll see your member groups and an option for what template to display if they aren't logged in.  Typically that's a login template using the Login Form tags mentioned earlier.

Comment: Question is: How to have a login form on FrontPage for users. You can create a user without member Module as you know.